# Configure appendix header

Tags: sectioning, appendices

In my double-sided latex document I'm using

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

This will display on an even resp. odd page the following

> SECTION TITLE resp. SUBSECTION TITLE.

However for the appendix I want to change this behaviour to the following

> SECTION TITLE resp. SECTION TITLE.

My appendix is embedded as follows

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[header,title,titletoc]{appendix}  
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}    
\pagestyle{scrheadings}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{appendices}  
\section{title1}  
\lipsum\newpage\lipsum\newpage\lipsum  
\cleardoublepage  
\end{appendices}  
\end{document}
```

How can I configure this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  it may be obvious to other readers, but it isn't to me, what documentclass you are using (and it may make a big difference).  it would be most helpful if you could post a small compilable example; it needn't be much bigger than what you have here, but we do need the `\documentclass`, and include `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sounds like you need `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii: Nope, the usage of `fancyhdr` and a KOMA class like `scrartcl` is **not** recommended.

Comment: The `scrpage2` package is 'obsolete' now. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` for this

Comment: Christian:  thanks, didn't know that because never used KOMA classes.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii: No problem at all, we all learn here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\automark[section]{section}` is the correct command, which will 'break' the standard `section|subsection` style of KOMA `scrartcl` class.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[header,title,titletoc]{appendix}  
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}    
\pagestyle{scrheadings}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{appendices}  
\automark[section]{section}
\section{title1}  
\lipsum\newpage\lipsum\newpage\lipsum  
\cleardoublepage  
\section{title 2}
\end{appendices}  
\end{document}
```

[image]